# Using a Custom List Item in Kivy and KivyMD

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I'm relatively new to Kivy and I'm practising putting widgets in a
Kivy popup widget. I was following this documentation, the section under custom list
item on page 14.

Here's the provided example declarative python style:

```
class YourContainer(IRightBodyTouch, MDBoxLayout):
    adaptive_width = True

class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return (
            OneLineAvatarIconListItem(
                IconLeftWidget(
                icon="cog"
                ),
                YourContainer(
                    MDIconButton(
                        icon="minus"
                    ),
                    MDIconButton(
                        icon="plus"
                    ),
                    id="container"
                ),
                text="One-line item with avatar"
            )
        )

def on_start(self):
    container = self.root.ids.container
    self.root.ids._right_container.width = container.width
    container.x = container.width
```

Example().run()

I tried to modify it a little bit to meet my needs. Here's my code based on the
example provided above but using kv:

````
kv_main = '''

MDScreen:

    MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "300dp"
    md_bg_color: "gray"

    spacing: 10


    OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
        id: sound_id
        text: "Sound Off"

        IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch:
            id: sound_icon_id
            icon: "volume-off"

        MyContainer:
            id: container
            
            MDSwitch:
                id: sound_switch
                font_size: 32
                    diabled: False
                    on_active: app.sound_callback(self, self.active)

    # I intend to add a few more OneLineAvatarIconListItems similar to the one defined above

    ```
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: 20
        padding: [20, 20, 20, 20]

        size_hint_y: None
        height: 250

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            id: vibration_button
                    text: "Continue"
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"


        MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"

        spacing: 20

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            id: setting_button
                    text: "Settings"
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "white"
            

                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            id: home_button
                text: "Home"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: "white"
            ```
````

'''

And this is the kv I'm using to trigger the popup window:

```
kv_button = '''

MDScreen:

    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "Press for Popup!"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: "white"
        line_color: "orange"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        on_release: app.open_popup()
        
'''
```

```
class MyContainer(IRightBodyTouch, MDBoxLayout):
    '''Custom Container'''


class SwitchApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(kv_button)

        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

        return self.screen

    def sound_callback(self, instance, switchValue):
        if switchValue:
            self.do_something()

        else:
            self.do_something_else()


    def vibration_callback(self, instance, switchValue):
        if switchValue:
            self.do_something()

        else:
            self.do_something_else()


    def timer_callback(self, instance, switchValue):
        if switchValue:
            self.do_something()

        else:
            self.do_something_else()


    def open_popup(self, time = 10):

        popup_content = PopupContent()

        popup = Popup(
            title = 'Info',
            content = popup_content,
            size_hint = (None, None),
            size = (700, 400),
            auto_dismiss = False,
            )

        Clock.schedule_once(popup.dismiss, time)

        popup.open()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SwitchApp().run()
```

Below, I have the class below whose instance is created in the code above and then assigned to the content attribute of the Popup widget.

```
class PopupContent(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.load_string(kv_main)
```

When I run the code, I run into a NameError: name 'PopupContent' is not defined. What am I doing wrong?